# How to set the focus to a specific pane, in CLIM?

Tags: user-interface, common-lisp, clim

At startup, `tagger-app` should give the input focus to `pane2` text-field. How can I do this?

```lisp
(cl:eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload :mcclim))

(defpackage :tagger
  (:use #:clim-lisp #:clim))

(in-package :tagger)

(define-application-frame tagger-app () ()

  (:panes
      (pane1 :text-field)
      (pane2 :text-field))

  (:layouts
     (default
       (vertically ()
         (labelling (:label "Pane 1") pane1)
         (labelling (:label "Pane 2") pane2)))))

(defun run-tagger-app ()
  (run-frame-top-level (make-application-frame 'tagger-app)))

(run-tagger-app)
```

I tried to study the CLIM documentation, but there are too much details.

Answer (score 4):

jackdaniel, one of McCLIM maintainers, answered on #CLIM IRC group in this way

```lisp
(defmethod clim:run-frame-top-level :before
  ((app tagger-app) &key)
  (clim:stream-set-input-focus (find-pane-named app 'pane1)))
```

Note the usage of `:before`, instead of `:after`, because `run-frame-top-level` is not a "normal" method, returning immediately a result, but it is an always running loop (as the name `run-...` suggests), that will terminate when the frame passed as argument is closed.

Comment: pane1 or pane2?

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following

```
(defmethod run-frame-top-level :before ((frame tagger-app) &key &allow-other-keys)
  (let ((pane2 (find-pane-named frame 'pane2)))
    (when pane2
      (setf (port-keyboard-input-focus (port frame)) pane2))))
```

If `pane2` were a stream pane then the solution would be a bit simpler (you could specialize `frame-standard-input`) – but it's not.

Comment: Apologies, posted at the same time as the answer

Comment: Many thanks. BTW, in other parts of the code, I'm using forms like your ``(when pane2 ...)``, because sometime panes are not initializated immediately, hence the code is more robust.